# Parsing dbus monitor output messages

Tags: python, regex, parsing, dbus

I am trying to parse the dbus monitor output messages. It has most of the messages as multi-line entries(including parameters). I need to parse and concatenate individual log messages to a single line entry.

The dbus-monitor output messages appear as below,

```
method call time=462.117843 sender=:1.62 -> destination=org.freedesktop.filehandler serial=122 path=/org/freedesktop/filehandler/routing; interface=org.freedesktop.filehandler.routing; member=start
int16 29877
uint16 0
method return time=462.117844 sender=org.freedesktop.filehandler -> destination=:1.62 serial=2210 reply_serial=122
int16 29877
uint16 0
method call time=462.117845 sender=:1.62 -> destination=org.freedesktop.filehandler serial=123 path=/org/freedesktop/filehandler/routing; interface=org.freedesktop.filehandler.routing; member=comment
string "starting .."
string "routing"
method return time=462.117846 sender=:1.19 -> destination=:1.62 serial=2212 reply_serial=123
int12 -23145
signal time=463.11223 sender=:1.64 -> destination=(null destination) serial=124 path=/org/freedesktop/fileserver; interface=org.freedesktop.DBus.Properties; member=PropertiesChanged
  string "com.freedesktop.Systemserver"
  array[
    dict entry(
      string "SystemTime"
      variant       struct{
            byte 12
            byte 9
            byte 0
        }
    )
  ]
  array [
  ]
```

This is the **regex** I tried to group the dbus messages(Parameter not grouped),

```
\b(signal|method call|method return)\b time=([\d,.]*) sender=([\w,.,:,(,), ]*) -> destination=([\w,.,:,(,), ]*) serial=([(,),\w]*) (?:path=([\w,\/]*); interface=([\w,.]*); member=([\w,_,-]*))?(?:reply_serial=([\d]*))?
```

I expect the output in the below format,

```
C [sender,serial] path interface+member (parameter1, parameter2, ...)
R [destination,reply_serial] interface+member (parameter1, parameter2, ...)
S [sender, serial] path interface+member (parameter1, parameter2, ...)
```

A sample output for the above dbus-monitor messages is shown below,

```
C [:1.62,122] /org/freedesktop/filehandler/routing org.freedesktop.filehandler.routing.start (29877,0)
R [:1.62,122] org.freedesktop.filehandler.routing.start (29877,0)
C [:1.62,123] /org/freedesktop/filehandler/routing org.freedesktop.filehandler.routing.comment ("starting", "routing")
R [:1.62,123] org.freedesktop.filehandler.routing.comment (-23145)
S [:1.64, 124] /org/freedesktop/fileserver org.freedesktop.DBus.Properties.PropertiesChanged ("com.freedesktop.Systemserver"[("SystemTime",{12,9,0})][])
```

How can the above expected result be achieved when the entries are usually multi-line? Also, the SIGNALS has multiple encapsulations making it difficult to access the parameters. Can someone help with the parsing of these dbus messages to the expected format?

Comment: Why parse the output of `dbus-monitor` when you can just use the dbus python module to get the data directly.

Comment: @hardillb The dbus-monitor output is piped to a standard logging adapter in our system. It is these logs from the standard mechanism that needs to be parsed.

Comment: Then you should probably change your system. `dbus-monitor` is not designed to be used as a monitoring component in a larger system. It’s a developer tool.

Comment: @Philip Withnall Unfortunately, the plan is to change later and not immediately. So currently, dbus-monitor output is the only option.

Comment: The _serial_ `61` in the `R …` lines of your sample output seem wrong, since `61` doesn't appear in the input. You should correct or clarify that, and also the `122` in the second `C …` line.

Comment: While we're at it, the first `R …` line has the _destination_ instead of the _sender_.

Comment: @Armali Thank you for pointing it out. I have corrected it now. The method call **serial** value must match the method return **reply_serial** value

Comment: Also the method call sender matches with the method return destination.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Can you suggest how the code can be rewritten to process line by line?

Here I rearranged it accordingly:

```
import re
import sys
regex = r'\b(signal|method call|method return)\b time=([\d,.]*) sender=([\w,.,:,(,), ]*) -> destination=([\w,.,:,(,), ]*) serial=([(,),\w]*) (?:path=([\w,\/]*); interface=([\w,.]*); member=([\w,_,-]*))?(?:reply_serial=([\d]*))?'
remember = dict()
sep = None
for line in open('dbusl.in'):
    m = re.match(regex, line)
    if m:
        if sep is not None: print ")"   # end the previous parameter group
        m = list(m.groups())        # each match is 9 capturing groups
        if m[0] == 'method call':
            print "C [{2},{4}] {5} {6}.{7}".format(*m),
            remember[m[4]] = m[6:8]     # store interface+member for return
        if m[0] == 'method return':
            m[6:8] = remember.pop(m[8]) # recall stored interface+member
            print "R [{3},{8}] {6}.{7}".format(*m),
        if m[0] == 'signal':
            print "S [{2}, {4}] {5} {6}.{7}".format(*m),
        sep = "("
    else:
        p = line.rstrip()               # now handle parameters
        if p[-1] in "[](){}":           # with "encapsulations":
            p = p[-1]                   #   delete spaces, "array", "dict ..."
        p = re.sub('^\s*\w*\s*', '', p) # delete spaces and data type
        if p[-1] in "])}":
            sep = ''                    # no separator before closing
        print sep+p,
        sys.stdout.softspace=0
        if p[-1] in "[](){}":   sep = ''
        else:                   sep = ', '  # separator after data item
print ")"                       # end the previous parameter group
```

Note that I also changed `m[6:8] = remember[m[8]]` to `m[6:8] = remember.pop(m[8])` in order to free the memory of no longer needed *interface+member* data.

Comment: Can I redirect the output into a separate text file instead of printing to terminal? When I tried, I am unable to encapsulate the message and it’s parameters in the same line.

Comment: @Kraken10 - Yes, you can; e. g. add `sys.stdout = open('textfile', 'w')` somewhere above the `for` loop.

Comment: I am getting an error when executing the above code. The parsed messages sometimes appear concatenated on the same row. This can be reproduced by  modifying the input (dbus-monitor message). In the input dbus-messages, on moving the **signal** message to the beginning or middle of the methods and running the code, the parsed signal (S) appears concatenated with the very next messages (C or R). Can you please check and let me know how to solve this?

Comment: @Kraken10 - I corrected the error in `if sep: print ")"`.

Answer (score 0):

If you absolutely have to use `dbus-monitor`, it’s probably best to use its PCAP output mode by passing the `--pcap` option to it. That outputs in a [well-documented structured format](https://wiki.wireshark.org/Development/LibpcapFileFormat) which can be read by [libpcap](https://www.tcpdump.org/).

Comment: To my understanding, the PCAP output Mode stores the messages in a .pcap file in a structured way and libpcap can be used to view the .pcap file. However, in my case, parsing the dbus-monitor output is the ideal option as no change in the system can be made and the monitor output is serialized from the external system to the connected PC.

Answer (score 0):

As you already have a usable regex, you can build on it by using it with `re.split` to get the needed message parts. Note that this yields a separate string for each capture group plus one string with the parameters, for each message entry. This example assumes that all the messages are in the string `messages`:

```
import re
import sys
regex = r'\b(signal|method call|method return)\b time=([\d,.]*) sender=([\w,.,:,(,), ]*) -> destination=([\w,.,:,(,), ]*) serial=([(,),\w]*) (?:path=([\w,\/]*); interface=([\w,.]*); member=([\w,_,-]*))?(?:reply_serial=([\d]*))?'
m = re.split(regex, messages)
m = m[1:]                       # discard empty? text before first match
remember = dict()
while m:    # each match group is 9 capturing groups + 1 parameter group
    if m[0] == 'method call':
        print "C [{2},{4}] {5} {6}.{7}".format(*m),
        remember[m[4]] = m[6:8] # store interface+member for return
    if m[0] == 'method return':
        m[6:8] = remember[m[8]] # recall stored interface+member
        print "R [{3},{8}] {6}.{7}".format(*m),
    if m[0] == 'signal':
        print "S [{2}, {4}] {5} {6}.{7}".format(*m),
    # now handle parameters
    sep = "("
    for p in m[9].split('\n')[1:-1]:    # except empty string at start and end
        if p[-1] in "[](){}":           # with "encapsulations":
            p = p[-1]                   #   delete spaces, "array", "dict ..."
        p = re.sub('^\s*\w*\s*', '', p) # delete spaces and data type
        if p[-1] in "])}":
            sep = ''                    # no separator before closing
        print sep+p,
        sys.stdout.softspace=0
        if p[-1] in "[](){}":   sep = ''
        else:                   sep = ', '  # separator after data item
    print ")"
    m = m[10:]                  # delete the processed match group of 10
```

The output with your sample data is:

```
C [:1.62,122] /org/freedesktop/filehandler/routing org.freedesktop.filehandler.routing.start (29877, 0)
R [:1.62,122] org.freedesktop.filehandler.routing.start (29877, 0)
C [:1.62,123] /org/freedesktop/filehandler/routing org.freedesktop.filehandler.routing.comment ("starting ..", "routing")
R [:1.62,123] org.freedesktop.filehandler.routing.comment (-23145)
S [:1.64, 124] /org/freedesktop/fileserver org.freedesktop.DBus.Properties.PropertiesChanged ("com.freedesktop.Systemserver", [("SystemTime", {12, 9, 0})][])
```

Comment: Thank you. The code works perfectly. However, I am reading the same from a csv file with each line of dbus message represented as row entry. I converted the csv file entries to a list of strings(each row becomes a string). This resulted in **TypeError: expected string or buffer**. Should I convert the whole csv file of dbus messages to a single string or is there a better efficient way here?

Comment: @Kraken10 - The most straightforward way is to read the file into a single string; however, this might be problematic if the file is large. I suggest you try it; if we need to process line by line, we have to rework the code.

Comment: I tried reading the file as a single string and it is working. However, the file size and entries can increase with increased log duration. Can you suggest how the code can be rewritten to process line by line?

Comment: Since this answer was already a full screen, I added another one.